# Series: Representation vs Expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series

I seem to be a bit confused about the different between representing a function as a series versus representing it as a Taylor expansion. Take for example the the function :
                          $$f(x) = e^{x}$$

I know that any function can be represented as a Taylor series, but what is the difference between representing this as a Taylor series versus representing it as an infinite series?

Thank you.

Comment: A Taylor series representation is *a* series representation.  Not all series representations are Taylor series.

Comment: But would representing e^x as a Taylor series at a given point be equivalent to representing it as an infinite series?

Comment: @bsmith144 yes, Taylor representation is a series. Just not the only series possible -- you can use Fourier series or Legendre series, for example; but Taylor is a very popular and most basic choice.

Comment: Thank you all. However in the Taylor representation of e^(x), one is still left with e^(x) terms - in the general sense. However, in the infinite series, there are no left over e^(x) terms. What are the consequences of this in terms of finding roots / solutions to the function?

Comment: Do you mean a finite Taylor series with remainder term?  I think that most people think of "the" Taylor series representation as being the infinite series.

Comment: Well that is exactly my problem. The taylor series leaves me still with e^x terms. But what if I have a really nasty e^x , and I want to get rid of the e^x's without taking the natural log? -- my logic was to simply approximate the e^x as an infinite sum, but some infinite sums (Taylor) leave me still with e^(x) terms